# Expiration time for a google app engine data store entities

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to setup expiration time for a Google app engine data store Entity?

If not is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no expiration time. The workaround is to create a cron job that deletes entities based on criteria that you specify.